# Why does hasattr raise a ValueError although attribute exists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I ran across something odd. See the following example:

```
>>> class demo(ctypes.Structure):
...     _fields_ = [('data', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int16))]

>>> b = demo()

>>> b.data
<__main__.LP_c_short object at 0x7f709c0550d0>

>>> hasattr(b.data, 'contents')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: NULL pointer access
NULL pointer access

>>> 'contents' in dir(b.data)
True
```

I guess the above behavior is intended, although I do not fully understand it. `data` is a field in a ctypes structure, defined as a pointer to an integer. It is uninitialized, i.e. a NULL pointer. It does have a `contents` attribute like one would expect (`dir` does list it), although accessing it would not make sense. I'd expect that `hasattr` also returns `True`, but instead it raises a `ValueError`. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasattr` is [implemented](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#hasattr) by calling `getattr` and seeing whether an `AttributeError` is raised.

Since accessing the `contents` attribute of a `ctypes` pointer tries to dereference the pointer you are seeing what you are seeing.